# Share storage/volume between worker nodes in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to have a centralized storage/volume that can be shared between two pods/instances of an application that exist in different worker nodes in Kubernetes?

So to explain my case:

- I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 worker nodes. In each one of these I have 1 instance of app X running. This means I have 2 instances of app X running totally at the same time.
- Both instances subscribe on the topic topicX, that has 2 partitions, and are part of a consumer group in Apache Kafka called groupX.

As I understand it the message load will be split among the partitions, but also among the consumers in the consumer group. So far so good, right?

So to my problem:

- In my whole solution I have a hierarchy division with the unique constraint by country and ID. Each combination of country and ID has a pickle model (python Machine Learning Model), which is stored in a directory accessed by the application. For each combination of a country and ID I receive one message per minute.
- At the moment I have 2 countries, so to be able to scale properly I wanted to split the load between two instances of app X, each one handling its own country.
- The problem is that with Kafka the messages can be balanced between the different instances, and to access the pickle-files in each instance without know what country the message belongs to, I have to store the pickle-files in both instances.

Is there a way to solve this? I would rather keep the setup as simple as possible so it is easy to scale and add a third, fourth and fifth country later.

Keep in mind that this is an overly simplified way of explaining the problem. The number of instances is much higher in reality etc.

Comment: This might interest you `https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/nfs-provisioner`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's possible if you look at [this table](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) any `PV` (Physical Volume) that supports `ReadWriteMany` will help you accomplish having the same data store for your Kafka workers. So in summary these:

- AzureFile
- CephFS
- Glusterfs
- Quobyte
- NFS
- VsphereVolume - (works when pods are collocated)
- PortworxVolume

In my opinion, NFS is the easiest to implement. Note that Azurefile, Quobyte, and Portworx are paid solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely look into this and try it out!

Comment: Another option to consider is to download the pickle files to each container on schedule, or if it's static put it into ConfigMap.